# What application permissions are required to create a user in Azure AD?

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm working on a simple Python application to automate creating/deleting users from our Azure instance on hiring/firing. I was able to get my script to create/delete test users using the `azure.graphrbac` library, but it required an admin user's sign-in credentials in the script which we're obviously not going to do long-term. I managed to get an app created and authenticated with `azure.common.credentials.ServicePrincipalCredentials` and connected successfully to our tenant with the proper settings, but I keep getting the below error every time I try to create a user. I have the below permissions (`Directory.ReadWrite.All`, `User.EnableDisableAccount.All`, and `User.ReadWrite.All`) applied to the application, what am I missing?

```
azure.graphrbac.models.graph_error.GraphErrorException: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

[image: permissions for Azure application]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that, `azure.graphrbac` library works with **Azure AD Graph API**
> that is currently deprecated and no longer supported.
> The error occurred as `azure.graphrbac` library won't work with
> **Microsoft Graph** permissions.

In my case, I registered one Azure AD application and granted MS Graph `User.ReadWrite.All` permission of **Application** type like this:

[image]

Now, I ran below python code where I initially generated token using **client credentials** flow and used it to create Azure AD user:

```py
import msal
import requests

client_id = "appId"
client_secret= "secret"
tenant_id = "tenantId"
authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}"
scopes = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']

app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id, client_secret, authority=authority)

result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes)
access_token = result['access_token']

headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}
url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users'
user = {
    "accountEnabled": True,
    "displayName": "Test User",
    "mailNickname": "testuser",
    "userPrincipalName": "testuser@xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
    "passwordProfile": {
        "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": True,
        "password": "xxxxxxx"
    }
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=user)
if response.status_code == 201:
    print('User created successfully!')
    print(response.content)
else:
    print('Error creating user:', response.text)
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, Azure AD user **created** successfully as below:

[image]

Similarly, modify python code to **delete** the Azure AD user like this:

```py
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}
url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/testuser@xxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com'
response = requests.delete(url, headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 204:
    print('User deleted successfully!')
else:
    print('Error deleting user:', response.text)
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Portal where user **deleted** successfully as below:

[image]

**Reference:**
[Create User - Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks!